# How to to install ros in debian jessie. Error with "sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116"

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It gives me an error "Host not found" when I run it. I also tried running the command without the port number but to no vain. In one post I read that it would help to rerun the command after sometime. But it has been 2 days and I am nowhere able to run this command. Can you please help me ? Is there a workaround for this problem ? Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222765/hello.-i-have-been-trying-to-install-ros-in-debian-jessie-and-i-remain-unsuccessful.-i-am-not-able-to-run-the-%22sudo--e-apt-key-adv---keyserver-hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80---recv-key-0xb01fa116%22.-can-you-please-help-me-?/) by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2015-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-18**:
Can you ping `pool.sks-keyservers.net`? On my system it resolves to `208.89.139.251`. If all else fails, you could use that IP instead of the hostname and see if that works. But it would be a work around, and points to some issue with your DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That was a brilliant suggestion. Thanks a lot. It worked :)

So as suggested in comments, I did ping "pool.sks-keyservers.net". I got the IP address from the command and used it in the command as follows "sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver 1xx.2xx.1.8 --recv-key 0xB01FA116".

Hope this helps anyone who has similar issues

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [mechatron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25364/mechatron/) with karma: 56 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-21**:
I would really call this a work-around. The `apt-key` utility not being able to resolve that hostname to an IP seems to point to some issue with either your DNS or the way `apt-key` interacts with it. I only asked you to ping it so we could at least rule out a general DNS failure,